# I posted a question on Aviation. Can I also ask it on Physics and Engineering?

Tags: support, questions, answers

I asked a question on [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/). I think that also [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) users and [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) users should be able to easily see my question; they may be interested to answer or to write some comment that could be useful. How can I achieve this aim?

Comment: Relevant: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Answer (score 11):

The same question, worded in the same way, generally never belongs on multiple sites. You need to word it in a way that is relevant to the site you're on. There's nothing wrong with including links to the other questions, but each must fit the site you're on.

For example, say you're asking about a particular cooking technique that is supposed to be good for your health, but that produces a result your children don't like to eat. You can ask on Cooking about a sauce or some other aspect that would retain the core benefits of the technique, on Health about what it is that makes this approach work and whether the same benefits could be gained another way, and on Parenting about how to get kids to try new foods that are good for them. It's all wrapped around the same question, but **it's not word for word the same question.**

Then you can edit each question to include links to the other two: in your case perhaps on Aviation you add "I've asked about the physics involved on Physics" and include a link to the question, and so on. That way people who want to go deep on an off-topic part of the response can do it in the right place.

Comment: And after some thinking about a question I've already posted some times ago if I decide to make a migration of a question from a section to another section, is it possible?

Comment: @d.pensopositivo you can't migrate a question yourself; you can flag and ask a moderator to do it but you're probably better off just asking the question yourself (and probably, as stated above, rewording the question to fit that site).